# Login not persisting across pages

Tags: php, authentication

Hello I have made a login system for my website dubleeble.com and for some reason when you login it only keeps you loged in on one page but when you move to another page it loges you out! How do I fix this?

this is the code I used:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

if($username&&$password) {
    $connect = mysql_connect("host", "user","pass") or die("Could't Connect!");
    mysql_select_db("db");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows!=0) 
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }

        if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword) {

            $_SESSION['username']=$username;            
            header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        }
        else
        header('Location:http://dubleeble.com/php/login/incorrect.php');
    }

    else
    header('Location:http://dubleeble.com/php/login/incorrect.php');


}

else
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

Comment: Please try to use a more descriptive title.

Comment: What does your code look like on the other pages that do not work?

Comment: First of all - SQL Injection - you should fix that.  Second, are you checking the session on every page after login?

Comment: Repeat after me: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: You need to check the session on each page to see if they are logged in.

Comment: This happened to me, check you have session start on every page!

Comment: Just as a pointer on best practice, you should avoid storing plain passwords in databases, store a one way encrypted password and test the encrypted version of the incoming string against the stored version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [my php login system does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405035/my-php-login-system-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- 'loged' is spelled logged...
- you should be using some type of password encryption rather than just storing text values you should
- use mysql_real_escape_string like I did to make sure sql injection
  isn't possible
- **make sure you are calling session_start() on every page you use your session variables**

  ```
  $username = $_POST['user'];
  $password = $_POST['pass'];

  if(isset($username) && isset($password)) {
      $connect = mysql_connect("host", "user","pass") or die("Could't Connect!");
      mysql_select_db("db");

      $row= mysql_fetch_assoc("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'");
      $numrows = mysql_num_rows($row);

      if($numrows > 0) {
          if($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password']) {

              session_start();
              $_SESSION['username'] = $username;            
              header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
          }
          else
          header('Location:http://dubleeble.com/php/login/incorrect.php');
      }
      else
      header('Location:http://dubleeble.com/php/login/incorrect.php');
  }
  else
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  ```